# Robocopy copiar una carpeta con un determinado nombre

Tags: windows, bash, consola

Quería saber si es posible copiar el contenido de una carpeta que contiene un nombre especifico, por ejemplo:

- Carpeta1
  **Sub1**
  Sub2
- Carpeta2
  **Sub1**
  Sub2

He probado con lo siguiente:

> robocopy "C:\origen\" "C:\destino\" "*Sub1*" /E

Así no funciona pero he visto que de esa manera se puede filtrar por extension de fichero, que no es mi caso.

Comment: los nombres de las carpetas "origen" que vas a copiar cambian? ¿Porqué quieres utilizar patrones para especificar la carpeta origen?

Comment: Por qué no hacer directamente `robocopy "c:\origen\sub1" "c:\destino\sub1" /E` ??

Comment: Dentro de la carpeta ORIGEN tengo cientos de carpetas, que a su vez tienen Sub1, Sub2... Y solo quiero copiar los Sub1

Answer (score 1):

Usa el comando xcopy:

```
xcopy C:\origen\ C:\destino\
```

eso copia todo dentro de la carpeta origen, sin filtrar

Comment: Con Robocopy también se puede hacer eso, pero yo necesito filtrar antes de copiar